# App freezes after print button clicked and print function triggered

Tags: javascript

I am facing an issue implementing print functionality in my application. I have a javascript function that is supposed to print the contents of a particular div when I click on the print button. Anytime I click on the print button, the print functionality works but it causes the main window to freeze. I tried adding a window.close also but didn't seem to work. Any idea how to fix this issue or any alternative on how to print the specific contents. Any other method I try ends up shifting all the elements of that div to the left.

**Function below**

```
export const printDiv = (id: string) => {
  let printContents = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML
  let originalContents = document.body.innerHTML
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents
  window.print()
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents

}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<body>

<button onClick={() => printDiv("print")}>Print</button>

<table style="width:100%" id="print">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>This portion should not be included in the print page</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me... Maybe you are running into different issue...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table, th, td {
        border:1px solid black;
      }
    </style>      
    <script type="text/javascript">
      printDiv = (id) => {
        let originalContents = document.body.innerHTML
        let printContents = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents
        window.print()
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents
        // window.close()
      }
    
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
<button onclick="printDiv('print')">Print</button>

<table style="width:100%" id="print">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>This portion should not be included in the print page</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok. But why does it render it differently?